# HomePod Stereo pair as output for a Mac

Tags: macos, homepod

I am considering using a pair of HomePod's as speakers on Mac. I did a bit of research and confirmed this is both possible and straightforward to do.

However, it is a bit unclear to me, if I chose to use the stereo pair as output for my Mac, will I still be able to use them as HomePods as well. That is, will I be able to use Siri, tab my phone to play a number on them etc.

Or will all this only work when my Mac is sleeping.